# Помогите знаки препинания расставить

Tags: пунктуация

Жизнь боль. Попросила принести power bank принесли но провод забыли. Вот как так можно. Принесите кто нибудь провод

Comment: Есть еще варианты заголовка: "Расставить знаки препинания помогите", "Расставить помогите знаки препинания"  :))

Answer (score 2):

**Жизнь — боль. Попросила принести Power Bank — принесли, но провод забыли. Вот как так можно? Принесите кто-нибудь провод!**

```
Жизнь — боль.
```

Тире ставится, если оба главных члена выражены существительными в именительном падеже

```
Попросила принести Power Bank — принесли, но провод забыли.
```

Power Bank — название, пишется с прописной.
Тире между частями сложного бессоюзного предложения ставится, если в первом предложении есть значение времени или условия и перед ним можно вставить союз КОГДА или ЕСЛИ (здесь: когда попросила).

```
Принесите кто-нибудь провод!
```

**Кто-нибудь** пишется черед дефис. Отсутствие запятых теоретически объяснить не могу, поэтому привожу аналогичные примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> Пиво откройте кто-нибудь. ― А где открывалка? [Григорий Горин. Чем открывается пиво? (1960-1985)]
>
> Вызовите кто-нибудь скорую помощь. [Сергей Носов. Фигурные скобки (2015)]
>
> Возьмите кто-нибудь Марту к себе домой. Лидия Сергеевна, возьмите Марту! [Вадим Баевский. Центральный поселок // «Звезда», 2008]

Дополнение.
Как подсказал @slava1947 со ссылкой на Розенталя ([Почему нет запятых в предложениях типа "Сделайте кто-нибудь что-нибудь"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439641/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d0%a1%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8c/439643#439643)), не являются обращениями и не выделяются запятыми названия лиц/предметов, находящиеся при форме повелительного наклонения глагола, если она употреблена в значении пожелания (пусть…): Приходи к нему лечиться и корова и волчица (Чук.); Всяк сверчок знай свой шесток (Посл.); ср. также: Кто постарше садитесь.

Answer (score 0):

Жизнь-боль. Попросила принести Power Bank-принесли,а провод забыли. Вот как так можно? Принесите кто-нибудь провод!