# Почему нет запятых в предложениях типа "Сделайте кто-нибудь что-нибудь"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, обращение

Предложения типа "Сделайте кто-нибудь что-нибудь" содержат, на первый взгляд, обращение (кто-нибудь), но запятых нет ни в одном из релевантных вхождений, найденных мной в Нацкорпусе по запросу http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=&gramm1=%28imper%7Cimper2%29&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%EA%F2%EE-%ED%E8%E1%F3%E4%FC&gramm2=nom&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=.

Примеры:

> Пиво откройте кто-нибудь. ― А где открывалка? [Григорий Горин. Чем открывается пиво? (1960-1985)]
>
> Вызовите кто-нибудь скорую помощь. [Сергей Носов. Фигурные скобки (2015)]
>
> Возьмите кто-нибудь Марту к себе домой. Лидия Сергеевна, возьмите Марту! [Вадим Баевский. Центральный поселок // «Звезда», 2008]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Предложения типа "Сделайте кто-нибудь что-нибудь" содержат, на первый
>   взгляд, обращение (кто-нибудь)...

Из [**Розенталя:**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126,8#pp126)

> 11. <...>
>
> Примечания: 1. **Не являются обращениями и не выделяются запятыми**
>   названия лиц/предметов, **находящиеся при форме повелительного
>   наклонения глагола**, если она употреблена в значении пожелания
>   (пусть…): *Приходи к нему лечиться и корова и волчица* (Чук.); *Всяк
>   сверчок знай свой шесток* (Посл.); ср. также: ***Кто постарше***
>   садитесь.

Comment: Спасибо! Я использую это в своем ответе со ссылкой на Ваш.

Answer (score 1):

Нашлась вот такая информация в статье Н. Р. Добрушиной [Императив](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2#32) (**3.2.1.2 Другие средства выражения подлежащего при императиве**).
[Императив —  повелительное наклонение глагола.]

Иногда подлежащее выражено неопределенным местоимением **кто-нибудь** или целой предикацией с местоимением **кто** (типа *кто может, кто хочет*):

*Сергей Николаич сгреб его спереди за руки и сильно сдавил. – Ну-ка, кто-нибудь помогите! – позвал он.* [В. Шукшин. Штрихи к портрету (1973)]

Такие случаи часто интерпретируются пишущими как обращение (местоимение выделяется запятыми).

Вывод: получается, что местоимение **кто-нибудь** в предложениях, указанных в вопросе, является подлежащим и поэтому не выделяется запятыми.

Answer (score 0):

Местоимения *ты*, *вы*, и т. п. могут принимать функцию обращения в следующих случаях:

а) в конструкциях с обособленным определением или определительной придаточной частью: Вы, третья с краю, с копной на лбу, я вас не знаю. Я вас  – люблю! (Возн.); Вы, чьи широкие шинели напоминали паруса, чьи шпоры весело звенели и голоса, и чьи глаза, как бриллианты, на сердце оставляли след,  – очаровательные франты минувших лет (Цв.); О, кто-нибудь, приди, нарушь чужих людей соединённость... (Евт.)

б) при самостоятельном употреблении, обычно с междометиями эй, ну, эх и др.: Эх, вы, бабы, бабы! Садовые у вас головы (Крут.);  – Эх, вы! И не противно вам сидеть рядом с Чебухайкой?  – бросает он на ходу (Крут.); Цыц, ты! Она тебе больше не слуга (М. Г.); – У него голова болит, – с сердцем посочувствовал Баев.  – Эх-х... вы. Жители! (Шукш.);

в) в составе других обращений: Милый друг ты мой, не стыдись... (Фад.).

http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/243